# Adding an adjustable constant current option to a LM5175 circuit

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, constant-current

Disclaimer: I'm no electronics engineer and I have no experience in this kind of circuit! I do occasionally design simple analog circuits and PCBs, barely messing with opamps.

Context:

I'm about to build an open source general purpose modular DC UPS. Meaning, it will switch between a DC input and a battery accordingly, charge the battery and regulate the battery's voltage. It will be MCU monitored and it will be able to talk to a host, if wanted. It's modular because the input voltage and current, the output voltage and current and the type of battery are meant to be arbitrary and the user may re-design, populate or configure in whatever way he needs. This circuit is meant to be as robust and efficient as possible (limited by me design skills), as it will be on for long periods.

The question is regarding the battery charging circuitry.

I'll be using the [LM5175](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5175.pdf?8ts=1612366793620&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F). My design is highly based on its typical application design (p. 20, fig. 24) and I'm using the webench to adjust it to my needs.

Here is the schematic so far. This is incomplete and the values are not yet chosen.
[image: The incomplete schematic]

I want to implemente a *smart, but not so smart,* charger, using CC/CV method for lead-acid or lithium batteries. All battery's safety features should be handled at battery side.

The CV is easily configurable my adjusting R2 and R3 but now I need the CC.

What I know I can do:

1. use the internal current limit circuit (ISNS+ and ISNS- pins);
2. messing the feedback (FB pin) so it can act as both CV and CC, whichever happens first;
3. anything else?

My main concern here is the stability of the system. I mean, I don't really care if it charges the battery at 0.9A or 1.1A. But whatever value the user got it adjusted, it should stay there. Also, I assume the user may use a dummy load, short the output or measure some specific TP to set the CC limit.

**Option 1.**

I believe this would be the correct way to go but I have no idea how to make this work. Usually the pins ISNS+ and ISNS- are connected across R1 (current shunt). Obviously this shut cannot be a trimmer.
These pins are connect inside to an amplifier and to a comparator such that when voltage across the current shunt resistor is higher than 45 mV the IC limits the output current, by lowering the output voltage. The functional block diagram is on p.13.

**Question**: is there a way I could add some circuit here so I could tune current with a trimmer between around 0.5A and, say 2A? How?

**EDIT:**
I came with this solution based on GreatScott's idea and adapted to my problem. However I have no idea if it makes sense to use the internal comparator like this.
[image: Doubtful idea]

**Option 2.**

I thought I could implement something like some *Chinese* designed switched mode regulator boards do. I have some idea that, by visual inspection, it looks like they mix the voltage feedback with a current shunt resistor and a trimmer. An amplifier is used to amplify the voltage across the shunt and a comparator to compare it to the trimmer.

GreatScott added this CC circuit to a board which only had a CV trimmer. [Here is the whole project](https://www.instructables.com/Adding-a-Current-Limit-Feature-to-a-BuckBoost-Conv/) and the schematic regarding this addition:

[image: GreatScott CC circuit addition]

**Question:** if this a good option to my problem, will this work here? Can you please give some help adjusting it to here?

**Option 3.**

Anything else I could do you remember? I found what looks to be two other approaches to this problem.

I found that the [TI's reference design around LM5175](https://www.ti.com/tool/PMP20660) has a CC setting to 11A but it's using something more around ISNS+ and ISNS- pins which I don't understand. [The schematic is here](https://www.ti.com/lit/df/tidrtw7/tidrtw7.pdf?ts=1612367138154&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftool%252FPMP20660).

There is [this thread on e2e](https://e2e.ti.com/support/power-management/f/196/t/955203) where it looks someone is trying to do the same using the COMP pin. I also don't understand the idea.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Option 2 will work, however compensating it will be a pain.

Comment: What do you mean by compensating it will be a pain? It will be hard to adjust to the value the user needs or it won't be stable enough?

Comment: I mean stability and good response ( shorting output, changing load ) is very hard in converters that are not intended to do this.

Comment: How about adding some resistors around the trimmer such that the interval trimmable is shorter and corresponds to something useful? Also, the trimmer outputs high enough voltage to be measured to set the limit spot. My only concern is that: I set it to whatever limit I want and the converter fluctuates too much without keeping a good CC source.

Comment: Look, how commercial products are compensated. They usually add capacitor across opamps and sometimes rc circuit near the shunt.